# How to get key vault certificate value correctly in terraform module to create VPN gateway

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, azure-rm

**Objective**: Trying to create VPN gateway in Azure via Terraform

**Problem Statement**: I am not able to get value of Certificate.

**Reference documentation :**  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/key_vault_certificate_data

Code that I used:

**In `Main.tf`**:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv-ab-vgw" {
  name                       = "kv-ab-vgw"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "standard"
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    certificate_permissions = [
      "Create",
      "Delete",
      "DeleteIssuers",
      "Get",
      "GetIssuers",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "ListIssuers",
      "ManageContacts",
      "ManageIssuers",
      "Purge",
      "SetIssuers",
      "Update",
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Create",
      "Decrypt",
      "Delete",
      "Encrypt",
      "Get",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Sign",
      "UnwrapKey",
      "Update",
      "Verify",
      "WrapKey",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Delete",
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Set",
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "kvc" {
  name         = "ab-generated-cert"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv-ab-vgw.id

  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }

    lifetime_action {
      action {
        action_type = "AutoRenew"
      }

      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 30
      }
    }

    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }

    x509_certificate_properties {
      extended_key_usage = ["1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"]

      key_usage = [
        "cRLSign",
        "dataEncipherment",
        "digitalSignature",
        "keyAgreement",
        "keyCertSign",
        "keyEncipherment",
      ]     

      subject            = "CN=VGWCreation"
      validity_in_months = 12
    }
  }
}



data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate_data" "kvcdata" {
  name         = "ab-generated-cert"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv-ab-vgw.id
}

# VPN

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpn-gw" {
  name = "vng-ab-hub-dev-we"
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  type = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"
  active_active = true
  enable_bgp = false
  sku = "VpnGw1AZ"
  ip_configuration {
    name = "vnet"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vpn-gateway-ip.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    # using gateway subnet for configuring vpn correct ? 
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.gw_snet[0].id
  }
  vpn_client_configuration {
    address_space = ["10.xxx.xx.xx/24"]
    root_certificate {
      name = "ab-generated-cert"
      public_cert_data = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate_data.kvcdata.key
    }
  }
}
```

Error I get is:

```
Error: Creating/Updating Virtual Network Gateway: (Name "vng-ab-hub-dev-we" / Resource Group "xx-xx-vnet"): network.VirtualNetworkGatewaysClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="VpnClientRootCertificateDataInvalid" Message="Data for certificate /subscriptions/xxxxxxx--xxxxx---xxxxxx--xxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-ab-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/vng-ab-hub-dev-we/vpnClientRootCertificates/ab-generated-cert is invalid." Details=[]
│ 
│   with azurerm_virtual_network_gateway.vpn-gw,
│   on main.tf line 1275, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpn-gw":
│ 1275: resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpn-gw" {
```

Key Vault is successfully created, and I see certificate also there but while using in creating VPN gives invalid data.

Can someone suggest, how to get this fixed..

Comment: I think you need the certificate, not the key file. So you can try with: `public_cert_data = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate_data.kvcdata.pem` . More info here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/key_vault_certificate_data#pem

Comment: Check [this](https://gmusumeci.medium.com/how-to-deploy-a-vpn-virtual-network-gateway-point-to-site-in-azure-using-terraform-d7202e901afc) out, here the author uses `azurerm_key_vault_secret` to store certificate as base64 string. Then, he tried with `public_cert_data = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.vpn-root-certificate.value`. I've not tried it but you can give a try with secret rather certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you are providing a certificate key, where in fact you need to provide the certificate itself [1]:

> `public_cert_data` - (Required) The public certificate of the root certificate authority. The certificate must be provided in Base-64 encoded X.509 format (PEM). In particular, this argument must not include the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` or `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` markers.

In order for the error to be fixed, you first need to get the value from the data source using the terraform console:

```
terraform console
> data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate_data.kvcdata.pem
```

After you get the value, you should omit the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` markers and add it as a value for the `public_cert_data` argument:

```
public_cert_data = <<EOF
MIIDKDCCAhCgAwIBAgIQPVBXb+qPT/mxZXY0HDo9djANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAW
...
EOF
```

Note that it does not matter if `EOF` or `EOT` is used [2] as long as rules are followed.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network_gateway#public_cert_data

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#heredoc-strings

Comment: Thank you  @Marko E shall give a try with pem  option...

Comment: Hardluck, I am still getting same error with pem as well @Marko-e

Comment: Ok, can you use terraform console to display the value for `data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate_data.kvcdata.pem`? If it has the begin and end markers, then you will have to provide it in a different way.

Comment: Yes it does print value , you want me to post it here ?

Comment: Yes like you said, it has Begin and end markers..., In Plan output, I see root certificate pem values  like this `public_cert_data = <<-EOT
                    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                    MIIDKDCCAhCgAwIBAgIQPVBXb+qPT/mxZXY0HDo9djANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAW ` and so on  but in example documentation you have given, there is not Begin certificate and end certificate line and also one more thing i observe that  there is EOT insted of EOF in that documentation.. does it matter I am not sure though

Comment: Yeah, so I thought the attribute will provide it without begin and end but it seems not. So I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I haven given pem key as value inline as per your updated answer. but still same error. any chance can you try same and let me know if that working

Comment: That's interesting. How about `public_cert_data = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.kvc.certificate_data_base64`?

Comment: If that does not work, can you add the part of the code where you provide cert data inline to the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246394/discussion-between-asp-and-marko-e).

Answer (score 1):

You can read an existing cert or created cert using the resource or data source and then create a local variable, clean it up and use it in your P2S config for your VNG

[Sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlKkA.png)

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "root_certificate" {
  name         = "cert"
  key_vault_id = var.key_vault_id

  
locals {
  vpn_cert = root_certificate.certificate_pem.replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "").replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "").trim()
}
```